# R: quickly simulate unbalanced panel with variable that depends on lagged values of itself

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate monthly panels of data where one variable depends on lagged values of that variable in R. My solution is extremely slow. I need around 1000 samples of 2545 individuals, each of whom is observed monthly over many years, but the first sample took my computer 8.5 hours to construct. How can I make this faster?

I start by creating an unbalanced panel of people with different birth dates, monthly ages, and variables `xbsmall` and `error` that will be compared to determine the `Outcome`. All of the code in the first block is just data setup.

```
# Setup:
library(plyr)

# Would like to have 2545 people (nPerson). 
#Instead use 4 for testing.
nPerson = 4
# Minimum and maximum possible ages and birth dates
AgeMin = 10
AgeMax = 50
BornMin = 1950
BornMax = 1963

# Person-specific characteristics
ind = 
  data.frame(
    id = 1:nPerson,
    BornYear = floor(runif(length(1:nPerson), min=BornMin, max=BornMax+1)),
    BornMonth = ceiling(runif(length(1:nPerson), min=0, max=12))
  )

# Make an unbalanced panel of people over age 10 up to year 1986
# panel = ddply(ind, ~id, transform, AgeMonths = BornMonth)
panel = ddply(ind, ~id, transform, AgeMonths = (AgeMin*12):((1986-BornYear)*12 + 12-BornMonth))

# Set up some random variables to approximate the data generating process
panel$xbsmall = rnorm(dim(panel)[1], mean=-.3, sd=.45)
# Standard normal error for probit
panel$error = rnorm(dim(panel)[1])

# Placeholders
panel$xb = rep(0, dim(panel)[1])
panel$Outcome = rep(0, dim(panel)[1])
```

Now that we have data, here is the part that is slow (around a second on my computer for only 4 observations but hours for thousands of observations). Each month, a person gets two draws (`xbsmall` and `error`) from two different normal distributions (these were done above), and `Outcome == 1` if `xbsmall > error`. However, if `Outcome` equals 1 in the previous month, then `Outcome` in the current month equals 1 if `xbsmall + 4.47 > error`. I use `xb = xbsmall+4.47` in the code below (`xb` is the "linear predictor" in a probit model). I ignore the first month for each person for simplicity. For your information, this is simulating a probit DGP (but that is not necessary to know to solve the problem of computation speed).

```
# Outcome == 1 if and only if xb > -error
# The hard part: xb includes information about the previous month's outcome
start_time = Sys.time()
for(i in 1:nPerson){
  # Determine the range of monthly ages to loop over for this person
  AgeMonthMin = min(panel$AgeMonths[panel$id==i], na.rm=T)
  AgeMonthMax = max(panel$AgeMonths[panel$id==i], na.rm=T)
  # Loop over the monthly ages for this person and determine the outcome
  for(t in (AgeMonthMin+1):AgeMonthMax){
    # Indicator for whether Outcome was 1 last month
    panel$Outcome1LastMonth[panel$id==i & panel$AgeMonths==t] = panel$Outcome[panel$id==i & panel$AgeMonths==t-1] 
    # xb = xbsmall + 4.47 if Outcome was 1 last month
    # Otherwise, xb = xbsmall
    panel$xb[panel$id==i & panel$AgeMonths==t] = with(panel[panel$id==i & panel$AgeMonths==t,], xbsmall + 4.47*Outcome1LastMonth)
    # Outcome == 1 if xb > 0
    panel$Outcome[panel$id==i & panel$AgeMonths==t] =
      ifelse(panel$xb[panel$id==i & panel$AgeMonths==t] > - panel$error[panel$id==i & panel$AgeMonths==t], 1, 0)
    }
  }
end_time = Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
```

My thoughts for reducing computer time:

- Something with `cumsum()`
- Some wonderful panel data function that I do not know about
- Find a way to make the t loop go through the same starting and ending points for each individual and then somehow use `plyr::ddpl()` or `dplyr::gather_by()`
- Iterative solution: make an educated guess about the value of `Outcome` at each monthly age (say, the mode) and somehow adjust values that do not match the previous month. This would work better in my real application because xbsmall has a very clear trend in age.
- Do the simulation only for smaller samples and then estimate the effect of sample size on the values I need (the distributions of regression coefficient estimates not calculated here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a split-apply-combine method.  I take out the `for(t in (AgeMonthMin+1):AgeMonthMax)` loop and put the contents in a function:

```
generate_outcome <- function(x) {
  AgeMonthMin <- min(x$AgeMonths, na.rm = TRUE)
  AgeMonthMax <- max(x$AgeMonths, na.rm = TRUE)
  for (i in 2:(AgeMonthMax - AgeMonthMin + 1)){
    x$xb[i] <- x$xbsmall[i] + 4.47 * x$Outcome[i - 1]
    x$Outcome[i] <- ifelse(x$xb[i] > - x$error[i], 1, 0)
  }
  x
}
```

where `x` is a dataframe for one person.  This allows us to simplify the `panel$id==i & panel$AgeMonths==t` construct.  Now we can just do

```
out <- lapply(split(panel, panel$id), generate_outcome)
out <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

and `all.equal(panel$Outcome, out$Outcome)` returns `TRUE`. Computing 100 persons took 1.8 seconds using this method, compared to 1.5 minutes in the original code.

Comment: Beautiful. Because your solution does not depend on any of the intricacies of the DGP (like that 4.47), I hope you will be fine with me editing the question and your answer to simplify things.